# GRASS r.in.gdal crash:procedure entry point sqlite3_rtree_geometry_callback could not be located in the dynamic link library spatialite.dll

Tags: python, spatialite, grass

I wrote the following python script to try to import a raster file into GRASS:

```
import os
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Desktop')
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['GISBASE'], 'etc', 'python'))
import grass.script as g
import grass.script.setup as gsetup
gisbase = os.environ['GISBASE']
gisdb = 'C:\Users\Documents\grassdata'
location = 'newLocation'
mapset = 'mTW'
gsetup.init(gisbase, gisdb, location, mapset)

g.run_command('r.in.gdal', input = 'middle TW', output = 'middl_TW')
```

But I got this error:

```
ERROR: GISRC - variable not set
```

And then this box message showed up:

[image]

It means that the procedure entry point sqlite3_rtree_geometry_callback could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\OSGeo4W\bin\spatialite.dll

And then this showed up:

[image]

Seems that the r.in.gdal module crashed just as I called it.

If I directly use GRASS GUI, this box message showed up and the program crashed after I choose one mapset:

[image]

How to solve this problem? I am using GRASS 6.4.3, python 2.7.6 under WIN 8.1

Comment: A potential answer is provided here:

http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/70035

Comment: I have one sqlite3.dll in that folder mentioned in that post, and I still get the same result after I rename it from sqlite3.dll to xxsqlite3.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I uninstalled OSGEO4W by deleting its whole folder under C:\OSGEO4W, now I can launch GRASS and use its module normally.